# CSS font no effect

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am using ubuntu font in my web pages. But, when I am accessing the pages from different PC, the font does not appear good. what I should do? A constraint is there: I can't use internet for accessing the font,like googlefonts. One more thing, I have to consider IE8 also. Please, suggest some generic solution.

Comment: IE8 requires `.eot` so use services like font squirrel to convert your fonts into different extensions

Comment: i have installed ubuntu font in my system. it is working fine in it. But , when i see it in another system, it is not so. do i have to install that font in the client's system? i am puzzled.Please help.

Comment: You need to use web fonts, check out http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: If you “can't use internet for accessing the font,like googlefonts”, the odds are that you are creating an application for offline use, not a web page. Is that correct? Then you could bundle the font into the application and use it with `@font-face` (it also works for font files in the user’s system, without having them installed there).

Comment: Yes, it is a web application.But, @font-face is not supported in IE8. Again a big problem.

Comment: Ok, please tell me one thing. Where do I have to keep my fonts. At client side or server? if at client side, then how should I do it in IE8, and if in server side, then why I am not getting its font as it is?

Comment: IE was the first browser to support `@font-face`. But in early versions it only supports .eot format. Please clarify your question, editing the question itself, to specify what you are doing and showing code that you have tried so far.

Comment: If you want to access the page from another pc you have to make your pc the server and put the font in a folder from your Web folders on the server